# How to send nginx cache key as a header?

Tags: nginx

I would like to send an NGINX cache key to a client. Instead of applying MD5 to "$scheme$proxy_host$request_uri" as described in the documentation (see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_key and http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_path), I prefer to obtain the cache key from the file name.

Let's assume I have the same `proxy_cache_path` as mentioned in the documentation:

```
proxy_cache_path /data/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=one:10m;
```

and the files structure is the same too: `/data/nginx/cache/c/29/b7f54b2df7773722d382f4809d65029c`

**Question:** How can I extract the `b7f54b2df7773722d382f4809d65029c` (or whatever key will be) from my *.conf?

I have considered integrating a C script to obtain the filename. Will this approach work, and is it a suitable solution to the problem?